# Uncover \tag on the last line

Tags: beamer, align, amsmath, overlays

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\begin{frame}[shrink]
  \begin{alignat*}{5}
    \uncover<+->{t_n &= a + (n-1)d  \\}
    \uncover<+->{t_3 &= a + (3-1)d \tag{1} \\}
    \uncover<+->{t_3 &= a + (3-1)d  \\}
    \uncover<+->{t_3 &= a + (3-1)d  \\}
    \uncover<+->{-20 &= -20\tag{2}}
    \notag
  \end{alignat*}
  \vskip-1.5em
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The \notag and \vskip is as advised in the Beamer manual (Sec 23.4). The (1) tag uncovers properly. But (2) tag shows right from slide 1.

What do I need to do make (2) uncover when that line is uncovered?

Comment: Using `\only<5->{\tag{2}}` works (but requires manual tracking of an overlay number). Using `\tag{2}\\ ` also works (but adds an extra vertical space after the formula).

Comment: @SergeiGolovan perfect. \tag{2}\\ is easier. Will you please convert your comment into an answer so I can accpet it?

Comment: I'm sure someone will come up with a better idea.

Comment: @SergeiGolovan I think your solution is very good, please post it as an answer - maybe with one small improvement:  `\only<.->{\tag{2}}` does not require to manually keep track of the number.

Comment: Okay. I'll do that. I just don't really understand why the second tag shows up starting from the first overlay.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

In the first slide, `\uncover<+->{t_3 &= a + (3-1)d \tag{1} \\}` will be translated to

```
\pgfsys@begininvisible
t_3 &= a + (3-1)d \tag{1} \\
\pgfsys@endinvisible
```

and `\uncover<+->{-20 &= -20\tag{2}}\end{alignat*}` will be translated to

```
\pgfsys@begininvisible
-20 &= -20\tag{2}
\pgfsys@endinvisible
\end{alignat*}
```

For the first case, `\tag{1}` is typeset at the `\\`. Therefore the tag falls inside the invisible scope and is not shown in the first slide.

For the second case, `\tag{2}` is typeset at the `\end{alignat*}`. Therefore the tag falls outside the invisible scope and is shown in the first slide.

---

To fix this, one can write

```
\begin{alignat*}{5}
  \uncover<+->{t_n &= a + (n-1)d  \\}
  \uncover<+->{t_3 &= a + (3-1)d \tag{1} \\}
  \uncover<+->{t_3 &= a + (3-1)d  \\}
  \uncover<+->{t_3 &= a + (3-1)d  \\}
  \uncover<+->{-20 &= -20\tag{2}
  \notag
\end{alignat*}}
```

Just kidding...

The correct way to include the tag in the invisible scope is

```
\begin{alignat*}{5}
  \uncover<+->{t_n &= a + (n-1)d  \\}
  \uncover<+->{t_3 &= a + (3-1)d \tag{1} \\}
  \uncover<+->{t_3 &= a + (3-1)d  \\}
  \uncover<+->{t_3 &= a + (3-1)d  \\}
  \alt<+->\beamer@spacingcover\beamer@startcovered -20 &= -20\tag{2}
\end{alignat*}
\alt<.->\beamer@spacingcover\beamer@endcovered
```